# On the action of $S_3$ on odd-dimensional sphere

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

I know $S_3$(symmetric group on 3-letters) can not act freely on odd-dimensional sphere $S^{n}$ by the criterion that every element of order 2 should lie in the centre. I would like to see an easy proof without using that theorem.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why do you object to using that theorem? The proof is very simple.

Comment: @MikeMiller I have seen Milnor's paper for the proof, it uses another theorem that is quite long. It would be very nice to get some idea so that intuitively the picture becomes clear why we cannot construct free action in case of $S_3$

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The proof in his paper is maybe 3 or 4 pages and self contained, except maybe for the invocation of Lefschetz duality, which is simply Poincare duality for a manifold with boundary. Could you explain more precisely what you object to?

Comment: @MikeMiller I understand the proof and it is very well-written. The proof of the paper is for any general group. I was just wondering that for a simple group like $S_3$ if it can be proof by some other arguments. I am sorry if my question is not appropriate.